# InvalidOperationException when serializing an array to XML as part of a HttpError

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

Is there any way to get around an `InvalidOperationException` when creating an error response from a `HttpError` that contains a collection?

It only seems to occur when the response is serialized to XML, serializing to JSON works absolutely fine.

The problem seems to be related to the fact that HttpError stores data to be serialized in a `Dictionary<string, object>`. If I add an array of a custom class (`FieldError`) it then doesn't serialize that to XML properly. However, when I directly serialize a class with a property that's an array of that `FieldError` class the array does get serialized to XML correctly.

Is there any way I can get the collection to serialize as part of a HTTP error as well?

The full response I get when the exception is thrown is:

```
<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.</ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace />
    <InnerException>
        <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
        <ExceptionMessage>Xml type 'xdt:untypedAtomic' does not support a conversion from Clr type 'FieldError' to Clr type 'String'.</ExceptionMessage>
        <ExceptionType>System.InvalidCastException</ExceptionType>
        <StackTrace>at System.Xml.Schema.XmlUntypedConverter.ChangeListType(Object value, Type destinationType, IXmlNamespaceResolver nsResolver)
            at System.Xml.Schema.XmlUntypedConverter.ChangeTypeWildcardDestination(Object value, Type destinationType, IXmlNamespaceResolver nsResolver)
            at System.Xml.Schema.XmlUntypedConverter.ToString(Object value, IXmlNamespaceResolver nsResolver)
            at System.Xml.Schema.XmlListConverter.ListAsString(IEnumerable list, IXmlNamespaceResolver nsResolver)
            at System.Xml.Schema.XmlListConverter.ChangeListType(Object value, Type destinationType, IXmlNamespaceResolver nsResolver)
            at System.Xml.Schema.XmlUntypedConverter.ChangeListType(Object value, Type destinationType, IXmlNamespaceResolver nsResolver)
            at System.Xml.Schema.XmlUntypedConverter.ChangeTypeWildcardDestination(Object value, Type destinationType, IXmlNamespaceResolver nsResolver)
            at System.Xml.Schema.XmlUntypedConverter.ToString(Object value, IXmlNamespaceResolver nsResolver)
            at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteValue(Object value)
            at System.Web.Http.HttpError.System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteIXmlSerializable(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlSerializableWriter xmlSerializableWriter)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph)
            at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
            at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
            at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.&lt;WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync&gt;d__1b.MoveNext()
        </StackTrace>
    </InnerException>
</Error>
```

I have the web api set up to serialize responses both via JSON and via XML:

```
config.Formatters.Clear();

config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter { SerializerSettings = { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore } });
config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter { UseXmlSerializer = false });
```

I have an `ExceptionFilterAttribute` that converts any of the custom exceptions my API throws into an `HttpError` and returns an error response:

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
{
    var apiException = context.Exception as ApiException;
    if (apiException != null)
    {
        context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse((HttpStatusCode)apiException.ReasonCode, apiException.ToHttpError());
        return;
    }

    base.OnException(context);
}
```

The base class of my custom API exceptions convert to HttpErrors like so:

```
internal virtual HttpError ToHttpError()
{
    var httpError = new HttpError(this.Message) { { "ExceptionType", this.TypeName } };

    var innerApiError = this.InnerException as ApiException;
    if (innerApiError != null)
    {
        httpError.Add("InnerError", innerApiError.ToHttpError());
    }
    else if (this.InnerException != null)
    {
        httpError.Add("InnerError", new HttpError(this.InnerException.Message) { { "ExceptionType", this.InnerException.GetType().Name } });
    }

    return httpError;
}
```

Then I have a derived exception class with an array which overloads `ToHttpError`:

```
public FieldError[] Errors { get; private set; }

internal override HttpError ToHttpError()
{
    var error = base.ToHttpError();

    error.Add("Errors", this.Errors);

    return error;
}
```

The `FieldErrors` property is a populated array and the `FieldError` class is declared as:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class FieldError
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Field
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Error
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public ApiErrorTypes ErrorType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

When I tell the API to return JSON the response I get is this:

```
{
    "Message":"The supplied parameters are invalid.",
    "ExceptionType":"InvalidRequestDataException",
    "Errors":[
      {
        "Field":"CollectionDate",
        "Error":"Collection date is not in a valid date format"
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've found to get around this is to create a new class that uses a `DataContract` and call `context.Request.CreateResponse()` to create a response from that rather than using `HttpError` and `context.Request.CreateErrorResponse()`